# For loop not working for XPATH in driver.find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

The output I am getting is only the first row item for the first column.
kindly let me know what the issue is and why the for loops are not working for this piece of code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url="https://www.up-rera.in/frm_sanitize_prj_search.aspx?regid=918"
driver=webdriver.Chrome("/Users/prakhargarg/Desktop/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Click Here To View Complete Project Details")
link.click()
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
rows=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShowTableApartment"]/tr'))
cols=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShowTableApartment"]/tr[1]/th'))
print(rows)
print(cols)
for r in range(2,rows+1):
    for c in range(1,cols+1):
        value=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShowTableApartment"]/tr["+str(r)+"]/td["+str(c)+"]').text


print(value, end='   ')
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Here is my code: Before that you have to install `pip install tabulate` with the work with table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from tabulate import tabulate

url="https://www.up-rera.in/frm_sanitize_prj_search.aspx?regid=918"
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Click Here To View Complete Project Details")
link.click()
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
rows=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShowTableApartment"]/tr'))
cols=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShowTableApartment"]/tr[1]/th'))
rows=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShowTableApartment"]/tr')
cols=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ShowTableApartment"]/tr[1]/th')

table = [[row.text.strip()] for row in rows]
headers = [col.text for col in cols]

print(tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="pipe"))
```